# refresh token from deleted Google OAuth application

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, token, google-oauth, refresh-token

What will happen if app will be deleted after user received token and it expired?
Could user refresh it somehow or this becomes impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to refresh tokens after application has been deleted.